# When MongoDB load databases?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

our software design assumes a database per user in an attempt to partition the data and later be able to distribute and load balance per user.

We noticed that the mongod process is taking a lot of memory even when no user has ever logged in.

So I would like to know how/when the loading occurs, if there is a setting that could do some lazy loading or if there is a better strategy to achieve what we want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe got the answer digging into MongoDB documentation. Databases are always "loaded" regardless if active or idle.

> To calculate how much RAM you need, you must calculate your working set size, or the portion of your data that clients use most often. This depends on your access patterns, what indexes you have, and the size of your documents. Because MongoDB uses a thread per connection model, each database connection also will need up to **1 MB of RAM, whether active or idle**.

So for a very high number of databases even when only a few are active, memory could be a big concern and our strategy seems need to be changed.